# CMAKE CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES(<pulse/pulseaudio.h> HAVE_PULSEAUDIO) ERROR (Raspberry Pi OS)

Tags: cmake, pi, pulseaudio, pulse

I try to compile aisdecoder by means of CMAKE at Raspbery Pi OS

In the CMakeList.txt tile there is a check for include fies.
`CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES(<pulse/pulseaudio.h> HAVE_PULSEAUDIO)`

**this does not find pulse audio.**

The pulse audio header is in `/usr/include/pulse/pulseaudio.h`

in the build directory i have the file HAVE_PULSEAUDIO.c in the folder
CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/

HAVE_PULSEAUDIO.c file:

```
#include <pulse/pulseaudio.h>
int main(void){return 0;}
```

I have installed pulseaudio

Comment: Try `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES("pulse/pulseaudio.h" HAVE_PULSEAUDIO)` or `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES(pulse/pulseaudio.h HAVE_PULSEAUDIO)` instead.

Comment: I have tried both with the same result. pulseaudio is not to be found.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache between your attempts? The thing is that the result variable for `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` is cached, so once header file is not found, it won't be searched again until the cache is cleared.